# Are bacteria repelled by self-lysis products?

Tags: microbiology

Intuitively, it seems like treating your own lysis products as chemorepellants would make sense, since getting away from a place where your kind are dying would be a Good Idea, but I can't find any papers that explicitly say so. Does anyone here have insight into the behavior of bacteria in the presence of high concentrations of chemicals that are normally inside of cells?

Comment: What specific chemicals or substances are you thinking about? What would *only* be found inside a bacterial cell and not in the general environment?